# import and use methods among different classes?

Tags: java, swing

I created a method called `calRoomCharges(int cusID)` in the class `public class transactions extends javax.swing.JFrame`

Then I import this class to the class called `public class AddReservation extends javax.swing.JFrame`

I imported the class as follows.

```
import myhotel.FrontOffice.transactions;
```

these both classes are in the same project.

But when I'm going to call method `calRoomCharges(int cusID)` in `AddReservation` class it says that there is no such method.

I did this in netbeans.

So howshould I import the class and use the method that I created in another class?

here is the method I created

```
  public double calRoomCharges(int cusId)
   {
       double tot=0.0;

        try
        {


            //Get Rates
            String sql="SELECT nights FROM reservation where cus_id ='"+cusId+"'";
            pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs=pst.executeQuery();
            int nights = 0;
                if(!rs.next())
                {
                    //handle no result
                } 
                else 
                {
                    nights = rs.getInt("nights") ;

                }




            //Get number of rooms  

            String sql2="SELECT no_of_rooms FROM reservation where cus_id ='"+cusId+"'";
            pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql2);
            rs=pst.executeQuery();
            int rooms =0;

                if(!rs.next())
                {
                    //handle no result
                } 
                else 
                {
                    rooms = rs.getInt("no_of_rooms") ;

                }


            //Get rates

           String sql3="SELECT rates from room_type a,rooms b ,reservation r where a.type=b.type AND b.room_no=r.room_no AND r.cus_id='"+cusId+"' group by r.cus_id";
            pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql3);
            rs=pst.executeQuery();
            double roomRates =0.0;

                if(!rs.next())
                {
                    //handle no result
                } 
                else 
                {
                    roomRates = rs.getDouble("rates") ;

                }



            //Calculate room charges

            tot =roomRates * rooms * nights;



        }
        catch(Exception e){}

       return tot;
   }
```

And this is the way I called it

```
private void EmpnamefieldMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                          

        int cusNo =Integer.parseInt(cusID.getText());
        double roomCharges = calRoomCharges(cusNo);
    }
```

Comment: Can we see your code (not just the method signature)? How are you trying to call `calRoomCharges`?

Comment: is calRoomCharges a static or non-static method?

Comment: yes.. please put the complete code snippet. I think you are trying to make a static call.

Comment: @AnandVaidya Code have put

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply have to either make the method static or call it through an object

```
public static double calRoomCharges(int cusId)
{
     // ...
}
```

and call it like that:

```
double roomCharges = transactions.calRoomCharges(cusNo);
```

or call it through a created object:

```
transactions t = new transactions();
double roomCharges = t.calRoomCharges(cusNo);
```

And a good thing is to name classes with a first capital letter so you'd have class Transactions

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 possibilities of calling the calRoomCharges method:

the method is a static method and you can call it via:

```
transactions.calRoomCharges(123);
```

the method is an object method, so you have to create an object first like:

```
transactions obj = new transactions();

obj.calRoomCharges(123);
```